# How to solve this second order differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

The equation is given by:

$$ \frac{dv}{du}\left(2 u\frac{1-uv}{1+uv} + u\right) = \frac{v}{2} \frac{d^2v}{du^2} + v\frac{1-uv}{1+uv} $$

I tried using `DSolve` for this differential equation, but it's not giving me any answer.

```
DSolve[
  v'[u] (2 u (1 - u v[u])/(1 + u v[u]) + u) ==  
    v[u] (1 - u v[u])/(1 + u v[u]) + v''[u] (v[u]/2), 
  v[u], u]
```

How do I solve this?

#### Edit

In case you want to solve the equation numerically, the boundary conditions are

$$v\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{4.9}}{2}\right) = \frac{-2}{1 + \sqrt{4.9}}$$
$$v\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{4.9}}{2}\right) = \frac{-2}{1 - \sqrt{4.9}}$$

Comment: is there any initial conditions !?

Comment: @Alrubaie There are, but the equation can be solved without the same, right?

Comment: @Alrubaie I added the boundary conditions.

Comment: Maybe ask at https://math.stackexchange.com and have the master integrators have a go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In case you want to solve the equation numerically, the boundary
>   conditions are

Your boundary conditions are not consistent with the ODE.  Did you check?

Looking at this term in your ODE

```
 s = (1 - u*v[u])/(1 + u*v[u]);
```

Then you say one boundary condition is

```
 z = Sqrt[49/10];
 (v[(1 + z)/2] == -2/(1 + z)) // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Lets check what happens to `s` at the above boundary condition

```
 s /. {u -> (1 + z)/2, v[u] -> -2/(1 + z)}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same for the other boundary condition

```
 s /. {u -> (1 - z)/2, v[u] -> -2/(1 - z)}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So you can not solve it even numerically unless you fix the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) It "seems" that the equation can be numerically solved with proper boundary conditions. If not, I will post the question.